# Загрузка постоянных данных на GPU и их использование с CUDA

Tags: c#, .net, cuda, gpu

У меня есть вычислительная задача на C#, которую очень хорошо можно ускорить при помощи параллельных вычислений, а точнее CUDA. В своем проекте я использую ManagedCuda. Однако мои вычисления должны запускаться много раз, но есть часть данных, которая постоянна для всех прогонов. Как можно один раз загрузить эти данные и использовать их в коде CUDA?

Comment: Почему бы сразу не запустить все вычисления на тех данных, чтобы не перезапускать процесс?

Comment: @aepot дело в том, что новые данные получаются от пользователя, то есть ин заранее все не известны

Comment: Вы же говорите про одни и те же данные, что-то не сходится.

Comment: @aepot Часть данных постоянна, а часть может измениться

Comment: @Mical Если Вы собираетесь это делать в пределах одного запуска программы, то просто копируете данные из `host memory` в `device memory` и используете в различных вычислениях одни и те же переменные. Если нужно, чтобы память сохранялась от запуска к запуску программы, то, наверное, нужно подумать о клиент-серверной архитектуре, где за копирование данных будет отвечать постоянно запущенный сервер.